# PHP class and method

Tags: php

Im using class.twitter.php (http://emmense.com/php-twitter/documentation/v11-methods-available/)

Im using this code:

```
$summize = new summize;
$search = $summize->search('#test');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($search);
echo "</pre>";
```

And the output is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [profile_image_url] => http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/327884498/Tobias_Zielke_ums_logo_normal.jpg
                    [created_at] => Sun, 03 Jan 2010 10:47:14 +0000
                    [from_user] => tobiaszielke
                    [to_user_id] => 
                    [text] => Ich hoffe unser See ist nicht zugefroren #Trocki #Waterproof #Test
                    [id] => 7329402210
                    [from_user_id] => 27862585
                    [geo] => 
                    [iso_language_code] => de
                    [source] => <a href="http://ubertwitter.com" rel="nofollow">UberTwitter</a>
                )

....
```

How can I take the [from_user], [text], and write it to a file?

Comment: just a little curious, are you missing out braces on the `$summize = new summize;` statement?

Comment: That how the documentation for class.twitter.php writes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = $search['results'][0]['from_user'] . ': ' . $search['results'][0]['text'];
file_put_contents('file.txt', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$search->results[0]->from_user` and `$search->results[0]->text`.

To write that to a file take a look at [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).